# Still cannot ssh as root

Tags: ssh

Made these changes to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
#StrictModes yes
AllowUsers root other users follow here
```

Added a password for root

killed sshd and restarted

Still cannot ssh to system as root (even using localhost on system)

Comment: You don't need the `AllowUsers` line.

Comment: Does not hurt, but with and without it, it still fails.

Comment: Alright, what does your server log say on an attempt to SSH as root?

Comment: Just a security side note: root login with password auth enabled is a huge vulnerability that can be easily exploited. If it's not crucial to you I would suggest 1). disable root login and use `sudo` for a particular user. 2). use ssh keys instead of password auth.

Comment: What does sshd write to your log file when you try to connect, and what error do you get from your client?

Comment: Setting the `PermitRootLogin yes` should have been enough. Change your root password again, `sudo passwd`.

Answer (score 1):

To test to see if there is actually a password for root in `/etc/shadow`, type:

```
su
```

Enter the root password.  If the password is accepted, type:

```
whoami
```

The command should return with `root`.

If this works but ssh does not, then your issue is most likely in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.  I don't see anything obviously wrong in the snippet you posted although I would comment out the `AllowUsers` line (which is only there to increase security and being hacked does not seem to worry you).

Please note that it an EXTREMELY bad idea to allow root logins via ssh!  You are pretty much asking to be hacked into.

Some distros (like Ubuntu) disable root logins and require that admin operations be done using sudo.  There are, of course, ways around this and you seem to be trying to defeat Ubuntu's security model.  Certainly your choice to do so.  However, the Ubuntu Team may have made other changes that disallow root logins elsewhere.

Comment: su followed by whoami returns root

Answer (score 0):

If ssh'ng to the system from another host. What you describe should have been adequate.
First, Verify the root password by changing it again, `sudo passwd`

Next, restart the sshd daemon, issue the command `sudo service sshd restart`.

Try  `ssh username@ipv4address` from another station.

Answer (score -1):

Perhpas, your ssh server is not listening on port 22
Check your IP table. Sometimes, for security reason SSH are listening on different For example: port 22022

Comment: I vote -1 for vague answers without explaining how to execute them. Also the question suggest that ssh works for different users, just not when he tries to login as root.

Comment: netstat show sshd listening on port 22